# how i can i import json file in javascript without using any server?

Tags: javascript, json

i'd like to import this json file in my JavaScript (test.js) without using any server (Node or others).

i searched on google, but i couldn't the correct answer.
when i used ajax, it need to allow CORS.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at file:/..../data.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

data.json file is like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
     "name": {
        "first": "Paige",
        "last": "Bools"
            },
      "marks": {
        "math": 80.89,
         "history": 78.23,
         "computer": 68.09
       }
     },       
 ]
```

in this case, how can i import this json file in my javascript file?
please give me any suggestion.

Comment: Can you validate JSON in online json formatter? doesn't look JSON to me

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712158/how-to-parse-a-json-file-without-web-request-or-web-server/35712278

Comment: If you need to bypass CORS policy, and let's say your JSON's URL is `https://example.com/data.json`, then you can access it through the CORS-Anywhere service with this URL: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/data.json`

Comment: What do you mean "without a server"? All files are served up by a web server, either a local or remote. Unless you mean a file on the Client's local drive. Where is this json file stored?  Your example looks like a js array with two elements, one object and the other undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The format is an array of objects. You can store it in an array in the same javascript file or if the data is big save it in another js file by just defining a variable and loading it using script tag.